# JavaScript Not Working When Included Elsewhere

Tags: javascript, validation, joomla, conflict

I have a script which is a simple HTML/JS contact form.
The site is based on Joomla. Specifically, one of the YooTheme Templates. 
It is also running WidgetKit.

I have had issues before which have been solved on here which were to do with my script including JS and WidgetKit including JS.

I removed my JS inclusion.

However, now the JS does not actually work on my script. The form gets emailed without validation.

The script works when not put into Joomla, IE, in its own PHP file so i know the code is ok.

It just does not work when added to Joomla. I suspect its some kind of conflict.

What i need is for the JS to validate the form AND send the email. At the moment it just sends the email.

Here is the code i have at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rppalmer12/style.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
//$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {

function isInt(n) {
return typeof n === 'number' && n % 1 == 0;
}

// Form validation
$(".darkBtn").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
var email = $("form.form_contact .email").val();

var zipCheck = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i;
var zip = $("form.form_contact .zipcode").val();

var phoneCheck = /^\d+$/;
var phone = $("form.form_contact .phone").val();

var error = "";

if(!email_check.test(email))
{
error = "Please give a valid email address.";
}

if(!zipCheck.test(zip))
{
error = "Please give a valid postcode.";
}

if(!phoneCheck.test(phone) || phone.length != 11)
{
error = "Please give a valid phone number.";
}

// Check if all is filled
if($(".gender").val() == 0 || $(".title").val() == 0 || $(".fname").val() == "" || $(".sname").val() == "" || $(".phone").val() == "" || $(".email").val() == "" || $(".zipcode").val() == "" || $(".dday").val() == 0 || $(".dmonth").val() == 0 || $(".dyear").val() == 0 || $(".insurance").val() == 0 || $(".sday").val() == 0 || $(".smonth").val() == 0 || $(".syear").val() == 0 || $(".hear").val() == 0) {
error = "Please fill in all the form.";
}

// No error ? -> Submit
if(error == "")
{

$("form#contact_form").submit();$(".form_error").hide();
} else {
$(".form_error").empty().text(error);
$(".form_error").show();
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body><?php  if (isset($_POST['action'])) {     $to = "test@test.com";  $emailfrom = "test@test.com";   $subject = "Insurance Quote";   $message = "\r\n Title:" . $_POST['title'] . "\r\n First Name:" . $_POST['fname'] . "\r\n Surname:" . $_POST['sname'] . "\r\n Gender:" . $_POST['gender'] . "\r\n Number: " . $_POST['number'] . "\r\n Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n Post: " . $_POST['post'] . "\r\n DOB:Day: " . $_POST['dobday'] . "\r\n DOB:Month: " . $_POST['dobmonth'] . "\r\n DOB:Year:" . $_POST['dobyear'] . "\r\n Hear: " . $_POST['hear'] . "\r\n Insurance Type:" . $_POST['type'] . "\r\n START:Day:" . $_POST['startday'] . "\r\n START:Month:" . $_POST['startmonth'] . "\r\n START:Year:" . $_POST['startyear'];  $headers = "From:" . $emailfrom;        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {      echo "Thankyou for using B";    }   echo "done";} else {    ?>
<div class="menu_contact">
<h3>Get A Quote</h3>
<hr />
<form action="" method="POST" class="form_contact" id="contact_form">

<label>Title:</label>
<select class="input title" name="title">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Miss">Miss</option>
<option value="Ms">Ms</option>
</select>
<label>First name:</label>
<input type="text" class="input fname" placeholder="John" name="fname"/>
<label>Surname:</label>
<input type="text" class="input sname" placeholder="Doe" name="sname" />
<label>Gender:</label>
<select class="input gender" name="gender">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
</select>
<label>Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" class="input phone" placeholder="Your number" name="number" />
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="email" class="input email" placeholder="something@domain.com" name="email"/>
<label>Postcode:</label>
<input type="text" class="input zipcode" placeholder="CW3 9SS" name="post"/>
<label>Date of birth:</label>
<select class="input dateDay bday" name="dobday">
<option value="0">Day</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateMonth bmonth" name="dobmonth">
<option value="0">Month</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateYear byear" name="dobyear">
<option value="0">Year</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
</select>
<label>Insurance Type:</label>
<select class="input insurance" name="type">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<option>Type 1</option>
<option>Type 2</option>
</select>
<label>Start Date:</label>
<select class="input dateDay sday" name="startday">
<option value="0">Day</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateMonth smonth" name="startmonth">
<option value="0">Month</option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<select class="input dateYear syear" name="startyear">
<option value="0">Year</option>
<option value='2013'>2013</option>
<option value='2014'>2014</option>

</select>
<label>Where did you hear about us:</label>
<select class="input hear" name="hear">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<option value="google">Google</option>
<option value="recommendation">Recommendation</option>
<option value="email">Email</option>
<option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="form_error" style="display:none;color:red;text-align:center;text-shadow:none;width:278px;"></div><input type="hidden" name="action" value="postform" />
<input class="darkBtn submit" type="submit" value="Get A Quote >" name="test">
</form>
</div><?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();" Trick but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any errors from Firebug or Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: no mate, nothing at all

Comment: I have been going at this for about 6 hours now. lol. I have figured out it is not just WidgetKit. Its just generally conflicting with Joomla

Comment: can you provide a link to your site please? Also, how are you adding the code on your Joomla site? In a module, component, etc? Can you please show that code instead of the code for a non Joomla site?

Comment: http://rosspalmer.info/all-products/motor-trade-insurance    - orange form right hand side

Comment: I am using Sourcerer plug in. I have just put the code into the site as i would any other code - in a module using Sourcerer

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok I think I know what the problem is. You're not adding the Javascript to the correct place. Instead of simply adding it anywhere within the module, use the following method:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    // your code goes here
');
```

Assuming you have kept to the standards for Joomla modules, add this code inbetween the `<?php ?>` tags at the top.

Hope this helps

Comment: Where would i add this in my code thats in the OP? Im slightly confused. Have never touched the Joomla code such as JFactory. Not sure how to use it

Comment: You can't simply add code into sourcerer. It's needs to be a proper module. You can use my [Module Generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras/module-generator.html) and take a look at the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Development)

Comment: I have used Sourcerer to add PHP before and it works fine? And CSS